# XmlDataProvider Source="pack://application:,,,/FinanceExplorer/Equity.xml"

Tags: xaml

Can someone explain the syntax in the source attribute here? What the heck is "pack:" and "application:" and why 3 commas?  I couldn't find any decent desciptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the MS documentation on the [Pack URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

The three commas represents a XAML resource file that is located in the root of the local assembly's project folder.

Answer (score 1):

The packageURI is actually a URI within a URI,so it is encoded by converting its forward
slashes into commas.

Therefore,the triple commas are actually encoded forward slashes.

Also you could replace something like

```
pack://application:,,,/logo.jpg
```

with this

```
/logo.jpg
```

The runtime will prefix the pack://application:,,,.